# How am I supposed to use the Radio Room?

Tags: fallout-shelter

My vault has a Radio Room 3 rooms wide fully upgraded. I have 5 people in the room with relatively high Charisma.  Yet it seems every session I run I get nobody to the vault using the radio. It seems like I get at most 1 person every 5 days or so of playing this, and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the Radio room to get more dwellers in my Vault.

Is the process of acquiring dwellers from outside normally this slow, or is their a better way I'm supposed to use the Radio Room?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The radio room does two things: raise happiness for other dwellers and occasionally attract outsiders to join the line outside your vault.

I have not tested the happiness mechanics in any depth, but that functionality is described on a loading screen so I assume it works in game.

Attracting outsiders works a bit differently from all the other resource production rooms. The standard resource rooms run for a set time, then flash with an icon when the timer is done and you (or Mr. Handy) can tap the room to collect the resources. Merging the same room into a bigger room increases the time it takes to generate the resources, but also increases the total amount of resources collected at the end. Staffing the room with dwellers high in the room's stat decreases the time for the resource cycle to complete.

The radio room is different. Each time it completes its cycle, it has a **chance** to attact a single new dweller. If it fails that chance, it immediately starts a new cycle, whether you have the vault open or not. It repeats this cycle until it successfully attacts a dweller. When that happens, it pops the icon and waits for you to tap it. Merging radio rooms together and upgrading the room both increase the chance of a new dweller at the end of the cycle as well as increase the time each cycle takes. Staffing the room with high charisma dwellers decreases the time taken per cycle, but does not affect the percentage chance per cycle.

What this boils down to is that a fully upgraded, full size radio room with six dwellers of 10 charisma each should attract a new dweller faster than a small radio room with a single low charisma dweller, both because each cycle is faster and because each cycle has a higher chance of attracting an outsider.

As a point of reference, my vault with a top of the line radio room with 6 dwellers of 14 charisma each (10 stat + 4 cha outfit) consistently attracts a new dweller every 6-8 hours or so. I send the outsider to die in the wasteland if their stats are not what I'm looking for, but that's a different thing. It's also rumored that assigning Three Dog to the radio room does something special, but I haven't confirmed that.

I also have not tested multiple radio rooms in the same vault.

### tl;dr:

**Yeah, it's that slow.**

Comment: With how the Radio Station was worded I was expecting a steady stream of new dwellers but the fact that it was really slow surprised me.

Comment: Happiness works with the charisma in the radio, the more charisma, the higher the radio boosts the happiness. Take a 14 charisma dweller out of your radio and you'll notice a drop in happiness (I noticed a good drop moving my highest charisma dweller out of my radio).

Comment: This thing is so slow that breeding is generally more effective than the radio room both for increasing population and for increasing happiness. However, I found the radio room invaluable when a fire killed 33 of the 36 dwellers in my survival mode vault. I was left with one male and a mother and daughter. Kind of hard to really expand the population without incest after that. Just two or three dwellers from the radio solved everything.

Comment: As GodEmperorDune says, when a dweller is attracted to the vault, you need to tap on the radio studio. This effectively blocks the studio from attracting more dwellers until you unblock it tapping on the icon. If you leave the thing running for, lets say, the whole night (or longer periods of time), the three-slot radio studio will just attract one dweller for that long period, but several one-slot radio studio could attract one each